# What is the difference between mret and ret instruction in machine mode?

Tags: riscv

Is there any difference between mret and ret instruction when risc-v core is operating in machine mode?

Answer (score 5):

1. `ret` is a pseudoinstruction, which actually is a `jalr` instruction, while `mret` is a real instruction.
   [image]

2. They are used in different situations. `ret` is used to return from a normal function, while `mret` is used to return from a trap (exception or interruption) with several side effects.
   From RISC-V privileged document,

> The MRET, SRET, or URET instructions are used to return from traps in M-mode, S-mode, or
> U-mode respectively. When executing an xRET instruction, supposing xPP holds the value y, x IE
> is set to x PIE; the privilege mode is changed to y; x PIE is set to 1; and xPP is set to U (or M if
> user-mode is not supported).