# is there any use of __attribute__ ((interrupt)) for riscv compilers?

Tags: c, interrupt, riscv

we can read [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) that the `interrupt` attribute keyword is use for  `ARM, AVR, CR16, Epiphany, M32C, M32R/D, m68k, MeP, MIPS, RL78, RX and Xstormy16`.

does it have any impact on riscv compilation using `riscv32-***-elf-gcc` compilers?

Comment: The simplest would be, take the compiler, compile with and then without the attribute, and compare the assembly code.

Comment: Pretty much every single MCU I've ever worked with needed some way to mark ISRs as unique functions. Quite often they have different stacking than ordinary functions and in many cases also different instructions for returning. Furthermore, some MCUs might require ISRs to be mapped to certain memory areas. So the question is rather: was there ever a MCU which didn't require some `interrupt` keyword (or equivalent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a separate page for RISC-V which claims it works. You can find it [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/RISC-V-Function-Attributes.html). Also you could probably verify it by compiling code with and without the attribute set.

I don't have riscv32 toolchain installed, but i managed to verify it using the riscv64 toolchain. You should reproduce the same steps using the riscv32 toolchain to make sure it works.

Using a simple `test.c` file:

```c
__attribute__((interrupt))
void test() {}
```

Compiling it with `riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc -c -o test.o test.c` and disassembling with `riscv64-linux-gnu-objdump -D -j.text test.o` we can see it generates `mret` instruction at the end of the function:

```
   0:   1141                    addi    sp,sp,-16
   2:   e422                    sd  s0,8(sp)
   4:   0800                    addi    s0,sp,16
   6:   0001                    nop
   8:   6422                    ld  s0,8(sp)
   a:   0141                    addi    sp,sp,16
   c:   30200073                mret
```

After removing the `interrupt` attribute the instruction changes to regular `ret`. According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73103306/5457426) this seems like correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, an `interrupt` handler requires a different entry/exit sequence than a normal function.  The differences focus in the saving of all registers in the interrupt (normally, only some registers are preserved in a normal function call) and the return instruction is normally different (e.g. in the ARM it has to change processor mode of operation, probably this is also true in the RISCV processor)

The interrupt attribute informs the compiler of the routine properties, so it can generate the correct code for it.